# SQL pivot in different way

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table. The table has a patient ID and review ID. For a single review many blood samples can be collected. For Patient ID **P1**, there are two reviews(1,12). But for other patients there are one review. I want first review for all patients in pivoted manner, then for second and so on. (they are ordered by ReviewID/Date) Is it possible to do! thanks.

[image]

A block of code is given below for db create,insert:

> `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BloodSampleData](
>            [PatientID] [nchar](10) NULL,
>           [ReviewID] [int] NULL,
>           [Date] [date] NULL,
>           [BloodSampleID] [int] NULL
>   ) ON [PRIMARY]`
>
> `INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[BloodSampleData]
>              ([PatientID]
>              ,[ReviewID]
>              ,[Date]
>              ,[BloodSampleID])
>        VALUES ('P1',1,convert(datetime,'18-06-08 00:00:00 AM',5),4)
>        ,('P1',1,convert(datetime,'18-06-09 00:00:00 AM',5),3)
>        ,('P1',1,convert(datetime,'18-06-10 00:00:00 AM',5),4)
>        ,('P1',1,convert(datetime,'18-07-11 00:00:00 AM',5),3)
>        ,('P1',12,convert(datetime,'28-06-13 00:00:00 AM',5),5)
>        ,('P1',12,convert(datetime,'11-02-14 00:00:00 AM',5),6)
>        ,('P2',10,convert(datetime,'21-06-07 00:00:00 AM',5),2)
>        ,('P2',10,convert(datetime,'14-02-08 00:00:00 AM',5),3)
>        ,('P3',22,convert(datetime,'28-06-13 00:00:00 AM',5),7)`

Comment: **YES**! It *is* possible. Congratulations.

Comment: Sure it is possible. What you need here is a dynamic cross tab. Crosstabs are an alternative way of pivoting data. They typically outperform the sql PIVOT and are easier to read. They have the added flexibility of being able to pivot groups of data like this. Here is a link to an excellent article that described this. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Comment: @SeanLange - Linked site seems to require registration, so is somewhat non viable.  For the OP - is there a maximum limit to the number of times a review is performed (ie, only 3 in this case)?  Or could it be infinite?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse that is unfortunate that it requires registration. Even so, it is free and knowledge to be found there is well worth the effort of registration.

Comment: OP - if you can post some ddl (create table scripts) and sample data (as insert statements) I will mock up doing this as a dynamic cross tab.

Comment: thanks, I will do, I am currently outside, please give couple hours to upload ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Whoever fights with monsters should see to it that he does not become
>   a monster in the process. And when you gaze long into an abyss the
>   abyss also gazes into you."

May god have mercy on my soul for this code, which gets pretty close. I don't think this is a case for a pivot / cross tab as others have suggested (although I long to be corrected and you won't have to use the monstrosity below), as we aren't breaking column values out into columns, but rather de-normalising in a different way.

Consider other formats that might be easier to generate, use the below if if doesn't disgust you as it does me.

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Report
CREATE TABLE dbo.Report (
PatientID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
ReviewId int NOT NULL
)

DECLARE c_patients CURSOR
READ_ONLY
FOR SELECT DISTINCT PatientID, ReviewId FROM dbo.BloodSampleData ORDER BY PatientID ASC

DECLARE @patient_id varchar(10), @review_id int
OPEN c_patients
FETCH NEXT FROM c_patients INTO @patient_id, @review_id
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Report (PatientID, ReviewId) VALUES (@patient_id, @review_id)

        DECLARE c_reviews CURSOR
        READ_ONLY
        FOR SELECT [Date], [BloodSampleID] FROM dbo.BloodSampleData WHERE PatientID = @patient_id AND ReviewId = @review_id ORDER BY [Date] ASC

        DECLARE @date DATE, @blood_sample_id INT, @review_num int
        OPEN c_reviews
        SET @review_num = 0
        FETCH NEXT FROM c_reviews INTO @date, @blood_sample_id
        WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
        BEGIN
            IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
            BEGIN

                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Report' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%' + CAST(@review_num AS VARCHAR))
                    EXEC ('ALTER TABLE dbo.Report ADD [Date' + @review_num + '] date, [BloodSampleID' + @review_num + '] int')
                DECLARE @update_sql VARCHAR(MAX) 
                SET @update_sql  ='UPDATE dbo.Report SET [Date' + CAST(@review_num AS VARCHAR) + '] =  CONVERT(date, ''' + CONVERT(varchar, @date, 120) + ''', 120), [BloodSampleID' + CAST(@review_num AS VARCHAR) + '] = ' + CAST(@blood_sample_id AS VARCHAR) + ' WHERE PatientID = ''' + @patient_id + ''' AND ReviewId = ' + CAST(@review_id AS varchar)
                PRINT @update_sql
                EXEC (@update_sql) 

                SET @review_num = @review_num + 1    
            END
            FETCH NEXT FROM c_reviews INTO @date, @blood_sample_id
        END

        CLOSE c_reviews
        DEALLOCATE c_reviews

    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM c_patients INTO  @patient_id, @review_id
END

CLOSE c_patients
DEALLOCATE c_patients
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.Report
```